# How to configure Google App Engine yaml file to handle 404 Error

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, angular2-routing

[image]

**Need to redirect all 404 links to index.html inside www folder**

This is my app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

It's a static angular 2 app , and i need to direct all page not found 404 errors to index.html.
There is (www) folder and inside that all file including index.html there.

Comment: would this work with PathLoactionStrategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So adding this as the last rule, will cause it to serve `index.html` if all other rules fail

```
- url: /.*
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/(.*)
```

But I think what you want is for it to actually perform a redirect; otherwise, your base url will still be some bogus url. You need to setup a basic request handler in server code to do this right (and in your case your server runtime is `python27`).

So add this rule to `app.yaml`

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

And then add a file called `main.py` with something like this in it:

```
import webapp2
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication()

class RedirectToHome(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, path):
        self.redirect('/www/index.html')


routes = [
    RedirectRoute('/<path:.*>', RedirectToHome),
]

for r in routes:
    app.router.add(r)
```