# Configure Google App Engine yaml file to handle 404 Error

Tags: google-app-engine, angular-routing, gcloud, angular7, app.yaml

After the deployment of my application on Google App Engine every things works like a charm , I can access all pages but when I refresh I receive a 404 error

Example : when refreching https://my-app...appspot.com/create-ad throw 404 not found

I tried 
[Angular 6 routes not found on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53315936/angular-6-routes-not-found-on-google-app-engine) 
and 
[How to configure Google App Engine yaml file to handle 404 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856895/how-to-configure-google-app-engine-yaml-file-to-handle-404-error)
but same result

This on my app.yml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: dist
- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

skip_files:
- ^.*node_modules(/.*)?
- ^.*json_data(/.*)?
- ^.*e2e(/.*)?
```

and also tried this app.yml config to redirect all url to index.html

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false
service: frontend-accept

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: dist

- url: /.*
  script: main.py

skip_files:
- ^.*node_modules(/.*)?
- ^.*json_data(/.*)?
- ^.*e2e(/.*)?
```

this is my main.py

```
import webapp2
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication()

class RedirectToHome(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, path):
        self.redirect('/dist/index.html')


routes = [
    RedirectRoute('/<path:.*>', RedirectToHome),
]

for r in routes:
    app.router.add(r)
```

But always get 404 when refreshing the page

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally the solution was to configure the app.yml properly

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
skip_files:
- ^(?!dist)  # Skip any files not in the dist folder

handlers:
- url: /((?:runtime|main|polyfills|styles|vendor)\.[a-z0-9]+\.js)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/browser/\1
  upload: dist/browser/.*

- url: /((?:runtime|main|polyfills|styles|vendor)\.[a-z0-9]+\.js\.map)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/browser/\1
  upload: dist/browser/.*

- url: /(styles\.[a-z0-9]+\.css)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/browser/\1
  upload: dist/browser/.*

- url: /((?:assets|docs)/.*|favicon\.ico)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/browser/\1
  upload: dist/browser/.*

- url: /(manifest\.json|ngsw\.json|ngsw-worker\.js|safety-worker\.js|worker-basic\.min\.js|ngsw_worker\.es6\.js\.map)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/browser/\1
  upload: dist/browser/.*

- url: /(.*\.woff)
  mime_type: application/x-font-woff
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/browser/\1
  upload: dist/browser/.*

- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/browser/index.html
  upload: dist/browser/index\.html
  http_headers:
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the 404 HTTP error code is due to this handlers:

```
- url: 
  static_dir: dist
```

As stated in the [Google App Engine official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#Python_app_yaml_Static_directory_handlers), using `static_dir: dist`  causes that all URLs beginning with the `/` pattern are treated as paths to static files in the `/dist` directory, so for example every time you call the URL `/whatever` the application will look for the file `/dist/whatever`, since it doesn’t exist you get the 404 error.

I believe that the following code will work as you are expecting:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

- url: /dist/index.html
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

- url: /.*
  script: main.app


skip_files:
- ^.*node_modules(/.*)?
- ^.*json_data(/.*)?
- ^.*e2e(/.*)?
```

The handler for the `/` endpoint will serve the `dist/index.html` file, as well as the `/dist/index.html` endpoint.

Handlers are checked sequentially and if none of the above handlers have been called then any URL matching the pattern `/.*` ( which is all of them) will call the main.app script (this will basically override the 404 error message).

This script is redirecting you to the `/dist/index.html` endpoint, so this is the reason why it needs to be handled in the `yaml` file.

As a final point I had to import `webapp2_extras.routes` to use `RedirectRoute` in the main.py.

Comment: i added **bold** `import webapp2 from webapp2_extras` in thrue main.py file and set the app.yml to what you advaice me but got **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()**

Comment: @AhmeX2 , the correct import statement is `from webapp2_extras.routes import RedirectRoute`